# How to use requestAnimationFrame with Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to use requestAnimationFrame with Promise, so I can use it this way

```
opacityToggle("layername",0).then(i=>"do some stuff after animation ends")
```

, but not sure how to do this. Here is my code:

```js
function opacityToggle(layerName, opacity) {

    if (!layerName) return;
    var requestID;
    var s = 0;
   
    return animate().then(i => i)

    function animate() {
        requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        if (s < 1) {
            s += 0.01
            s = +s.toFixed(2)
            console.log('s', layerName, s, opacity);
            map.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'fill-opacity', s);
        } else {
            cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
            return new Promise(resolve => resolve)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @Terry has the simple solution of wrapping just everything in the promise constructor, you get the real power of promises if you promisify only the `requestAnimationFrame` call itself:

```
async function opacityToggle(layerName, opacity) { /*
^^^^^ */
    if (!layerName) return;

    var s = 0;
    while (s < 1) {
//  ^^^^^
        s += 0.01
        s = +s.toFixed(2)
        console.log('s', layerName, s, opacity);
        map.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'fill-opacity', s);

        await new Promise(resolve => {
//      ^^^^^
            requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        });
    }
}
```

If you can't use `async`/`await` and/or want to do it with the recursive approach, it would be

```
function opacityToggle(layerName, opacity) {
    if (!layerName) return Promise.resolve();

    var s = 0;
    return animate();

    function animate() {
        if (s < 1) {
            s += 0.01
            s = +s.toFixed(2)
            console.log('s', layerName, s, opacity);
            map.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'fill-opacity', s);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
//          ^^^^^^
                requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
            }).then(animate);
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `return Promise.resolve(); ` should be flipped with `return new Promise(resolve => {
                requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
            }).then(animate);` but that works, thanks

Comment: and what if I have to put `return animate()` inside a setTimeout?

Comment: Ah, indeed :-) For starting the animation after a timeout, just chain it to a `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, …))`

Comment: `return new Promise(requestAnimationFrame).then(animate);` would just work as fine ;-)

Comment: @Andrea right. I generally try to avoid passing non-void-returning functions though, and like being explicit here

Comment: you are ignoring the `rAF` returned value, and so would do my trick, but yeah, it was just a tiny trick to make code shorter, I like being explicit too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're slightly over-complicating the return statement of your `opacityToggle` function. You simply return the promise and encapsulate all the RAF logic inside of it. This should be sufficient:

```
function opacityToggle(layerName, opacity) {

    if (!layerName) return;
    var requestID;
    var s = 0;

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Animation steps
        function animate() {
            if (s < 1) {
                s += 0.01
                s = +s.toFixed(2)
                console.log('s', layerName, s, opacity);
                map.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'fill-opacity', s);

                requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            } else {
                // If animation is complete, then we resolve the promise
                cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
                resolve();
            }
        }

        // Start animation
        requestID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    });
}
```

It is unclear in your question tho, of what value you want to resolve the promise with. You can simply provide it as `resolve(yourResolvedValueHere)` if you want to do so.

Comment: You don't need to `cancelAnimationFrame(requestID)` if you do the `requestAnimationFrame(animate)` conditionally

Comment: @Bergi I need to cancel it when s is more than 1

Comment: @SERG `requestID` never refers to more than one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful trick that you can try. But this trick may forgo the benefits of using the animation frame on some systems, like no flicker and shear.

```
async function sleep() {
    return new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);
}
    
async function loop() {
    do {
    // render things here
    // you can also await stuff in here
    await sleep();
    } while (1);
}

loop();
```